# xml schema and java objects

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have received xml schema from a third party vendor. However the xml schema and the xml don't seem to match atleast that is my guess. I am using Intellij and use the JAXB plugin to get JAVA objects.

My code never returns the field values  i.e. it never returns "my string value" back from xml

```
<field type="Address">
                <value type="Value">my string value</value>
            </field>
```

I get data back as

```
0 = {FieldType@1372} 
 characters = null
 value = {FieldTypeType@1381} "ADDRESS"
  value = {String@1383} "Address"
  data = null
  name = {String@1382} "ADDRESS"
  ordinal = 8
1 = {FieldType@1373} 
 characters = null
 value = {FieldTypeType@1387} "CARD_NUMBER"
2 = {FieldType@1374} 
 characters = null
 value = {FieldTypeType@1389} "DATE"
3 = {FieldType@1375}
```

I have the xml as this (part of it)

```
<field type="Address">
            <value type="Value">my string value</value>
        </field>
        <field type="CardNumber">
            <value type="Value">xxxxx</value>
        </field>
        <field type="Date">
            <value type="Day">21</value>
            <value type="Month">4</value>
            <value type="Year">2015</value>
        </field>
        <field type="Phone">
            <value type="Value">212XXX</value>
        </field>
        <field type="SubTotal">
            <value type="value">XXX</value>
        </field>
```

and schema is

```
 <xs:complexType name="receiptType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="field" type="tns:fieldType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="lineItem" type="tns:lineItemType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="recognizedText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="paymentType" type="tns:paymentTypeType"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="cardType" type="tns:cardTypeType"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="purchaseType" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="paymentTypeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Card"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Cash"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Undefined"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="cardTypeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="AmericanExpress"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="EuroCard"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="MasterCard"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Visa"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Undefined"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="fieldType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="value" type="tns:valueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="characters" type="tns:charactersType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="tns:fieldTypeType"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="valueType">
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:valueTypeType"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="valueTypeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Value"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Day"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Month"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Year"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Hour"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Minute"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Second"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="fieldTypeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Total"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="SubTotal"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="CardNumber"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="TotalTax"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Tax"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Date"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Time"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Vendor"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Address"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Phone"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="Fax"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: You can generate sample `xml` that matches the provided schema file using the xsd and then verify your guess.

Comment: Don't guess wether your XML matches against the schema. The purpose of an XML schema is to be able to validate an XML document against the schema. There are even online validators available like [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html).

Comment: Thanks, I used this tool and created my own xsd which seems to do work pretty well with my xml set. thanks for the suggestions. The schema I was using was erroneous.